Were top-ranked launch propulsion technologies, TBCC and RBCC, already flight-proven in 2012 when the NASA Space Technology report was published?
The publication, "NASA Space Technology Roadmaps and Priorities: Restoring NASA's Technological Edge and Paving the Way for a New Era in Space (2012)" states that NASA's top technical challenge for all three of its technology objectives was to:

Improved Access to Space: Dramatically reduce the total cost and increase reliability and safety of access to space.

In Figure D.1 of that report, two air-breathing propulsion systems technologies called "Turbine-Based Combined Cycle" and "Rocket-Based Combined-Cycle" tied for first place in a priority ranking of 32 technologies that they assessed to help address the challenge.

The report states...

Panel 1 identified two high-priority technologies in TA01: Turbine Based Combined Cycle (TBCC) and Rocket Based Combined Cycle (RBCC). The justification for ranking each of these technologies as a high priority is discussed below. TBCC and RBCC would benefit other users, such as the DOD, which also has the ability to advance these technologies. However, they are ranked as a high priority for NASA because they would provide a large benefit to NASA and because they are a good match with NASA’s mission and expertise. In fact, the current state of the art in TBCC and RBCC technology has benefited from past research supported by NASA’s aeronautics research and technology program.

This report from NASA defines TBCC as...

1 .3 .1 Turbine-Based Combined-Cycle: A combination propulsion system that consists of a turbine engine and ram or dual-mode scramjet. Concepts generally employ separate ducts for the turbine engine and ramjet flows, although a common variable-geometry inlet or nozzle is often proposed.

and

1 .3 .2 Rocket-Based Combined-Cycle: A combined-cycle propulsion system that generally consists of an ejector-ramjet or rocket mode for liftoff, followed by ramjet, scramjet, and rocket modes for acceleration to orbital velocity. Synergy between the various cycles is taken advantage of by using a common variable geometry flow-path for all modes.

I'd like to gain more insight on whether either TBCC or RBCC were already flight-proven when this report was published. For example were they used in Lockheed A-12, the SR-71, or some other vehicle? What was the TRL level of these technologies at the time? What was the difference between the state-of-the-art and NASA's goal wrt/ advancing each of these technologies?
